Understanding units (height, width, x,y) in konvajs
I'm mis-understanding something about units in konvajs.
For simplicity, I'm using 1cm = 1px.  I have a wall that is 300cm x 300cm, and pictures that are 40x60 (or 60x40 if portrait).
I've created the group with a width and height of 300, then I add the pictures as images, also with a width and height.
But clearly this isn't right, as you can see from the picture below. Even though the width is only 60, it's taking up most of the width of the 300-wide group.
I can inspect the canvas and see aspect-ratio: auto 843 / 571;
On a related note, how can I debug the canvas?  Maybe that'll help.  But more importantly is getting these relative units right, the x,y and width,height.
Thanks.


I see my problem -- the Image element needs to set the height and width, not just the container for it.
